# Apache doesn't load .php files

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

First, sorry for my English and asking something that it's quite answered all over the web.
I've read a lot of post about this problem but I still can't find the solution.

I'm a web developer who recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows 7. I had a website done (it's online and working) and I set up LAMP to keep working with it.
I made a test.php file with: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
and put it on `/var/www/html` directory, it shows all the information about the php and I was really happy: "Ok, it's all done, tomorrow I will work hard"

But I placed my whole web into `/var/www/html` , not in a folder, the index.php is in `/var/www/html` but guess what: doesn't load any of my .php files, the browser just keep thinking.

What I did:

1. I rebooted Apache: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
2. I tried again with the test.php file and it works fine
3. I put in `/var/www/html` a .html file and works fine.
4. I looked for `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf` and it says:
   `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`
5. I looked for `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf` and it says:
   `DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php ...`

Edit*

I think it's something related to phpmyadmin, like if I'm not able to connect with the database. But I got nothing on the screen when trying to load the page so...I'm not sure.

I can access to the url `localhost/phpmyadmin` and I edited the connection.php file like this:

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_rakstadconnection = "localhost";
$database_rakstadconnection = "rakstadclandb";
$username_rakstadconnection = "root";
$password_rakstadconnection = "admin";
$rakstadconnection = mysql_connect($hostname_rakstadconnection, $username_rakstadconnection, $password_rakstadconnection) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
?>
```

The name of the database is correct, like the user and password.

http://i89.photobucket.com/albums/k220/Haddex/Capturadepantallade2014-06-09112609_zpsc45ddb72.png

http://i89.photobucket.com/albums/k220/Haddex/Capturadepantallade2014-06-09112120_zps0b9e15f7.png

*Edit2: could this be because it's a website that I brought to Linux from Windows? I used Dreamweaver.

*Edit3: I changed the # to /**/, nothing. The error.log file says:

```
[Mon Jun 09 17:08:13.627881 2014] [:error] [pid 1517] [client 127.0.0.1:46663] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/Connections/rakstadconnection.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 1
[Mon Jun 09 17:08:13.627933 2014] [:error] [pid 1517] [client 127.0.0.1:46663] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Connections/rakstadconnection.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 1
```

I'm reading error log but...should I add a linux path into a my index.php file? Don't think so.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your error log say?
Also, '#' for comments in php is now deprecated I believe.
use `/* This */` or `//This works too`

Comment: That's mostly the problem, that I don't get any error (at least on the browser screen). When not able to connect or syntax error I always see some php error message on the browser on WINDOWS, but here I don't see anything. Testphp.php (phpinfo()) works perfect, but my .php files return an empty webpage. I always use /**/ for comments, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You are probably getting a php error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: like @Duncubuntu says try using the `//` or `/* */` for comments, you say you always do but your not in this case you have `#` I didn't even know that was ever an acceptable comment marker.

Comment: I added the error.log in the Edit3 at the end of the question, thanks guys, hope to fix it. I don't like to boot Windows just to do some web development.

Comment: As far as I know, at least in my website folder, I don't have any .htaccess or init file. Same folder works fine with Wamp on Windows. Should I create .htaccess and add...something to fix this?

Comment: I agree, it could very well be a problem with your include paths. Or like @dan08 says below, make sure your permissions are correct first. (I like to stick with 755 for folders, 644 for files). Also: Post your include lines from index.php. For future reference as well: if PHP gives you a blank screen, its almost always a fatal error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a problem with the permission of the files. If apache (or www-data) does not have read permission the pages will not show.

this error seems to indicate that:

```
`[Mon Jun 09 17:08:13.627881 2014] [:error] [pid 1517] [client 127.0.0.1:46663] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/Connections/rakstadconnection.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 1`
```

Make `www-data` the owner of the directory and everything in it. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/<siteFolder>`.

Then set the privileges to give the owner and group read and write and execute privileges and everyone else just read privileges `sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/html/<siteFolder>`.

---

Comment: Thank you dan08, you just made my day. It was the chmod.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on Unix permissions, because it will be important to get them right if your running a public web server on a Linux box. Here's a good start: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm